# Does almost every pair of elements in a compact Lie group generates the connected component?

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups

It is known that almost every pair of elements in a connected compact Lie group (topologically) generates the group.

Obviously this isn't true for non-connected groups but

> Given a compact Lie group $G$, is it true that almost every pair of elements of $G$ generates a subgroup containing the connected component $G^\circ$ of 1?

Comment: Which connected component? Are the elements supposed to be in the same connected component?

Comment: And which group?

Comment: No need to vote for close, without leaving the OP time to clarify the question. It's clear that "the connected component" meant "the connected component of 1".

Comment: @YCor if that were the case, the question would be trivial (since the connected component of $1$ is a connected compact Lie group). I don't think that's what the OP means.

Comment: @IgorRivin: Is it trivial?  Note that the question is (currently) about almost every pair of elements of $G$, not of $G^\circ$.  Anyway, if the closed subgroup generated by $x,y$ contains any connected component of $G$, then it contains $G^\circ$.

Comment: The component group of $G$ is finite, so take powers until both of the elements land in $G_0$. The resulting probability distribution on $G_0$ is surely close enough to Haar measure that the result for the connected case can be applied from here.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I thought about that too, but I'm stuck on showing the "surely" part...

Comment: The infinite dihedral group $O_2({\bf R})$ is a famous counterexample to "close enough to Haar measure":  All elements of the non-identity component are involutions!  But it still does not refute the OP's conjecture.

Comment: @Ycor Thank you for clarifying my question, I thought this was clear from the context (and like Nate said, if a group contains some connected component of the group then it also contains $G^0$).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan This was my first idea too, but it's not true. You can take the semi direct product of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}=\{\sigma,1\}$ with $S^1$ using the action $\sigma.x=-x$. Then every element not in the connected component (of $1$) is of order $2$. However, it's easy to see in this group it is indeed true almost every pair of elements generate a group containing the connected component of $1$.

Comment: Ah, OK, now I understand the question!

Comment: Is this guaranteed (maybe even obvious) if we assume that $G^0$ is commutative (a torus)?

Comment: @IgorRivin this is why when you think a question is trivial, writing a comment and waiting for answers can be useful before voting to close. It often occurs to me too. (Btw you should retract your closing vote.)

Comment: @YCor I did not think the question was trivial, but I could not understand what it was, and so the question certainly fit under the "unclear what you are asking" category.

Comment: @user44191 I don't think so. I couldn't even prove this for the case $G$ is a semidirect product of a a subgroup $\Delta$ of $S_n$ and an $n$-dimensional torus (where $\Delta$ acts by permuting the coordinates of the torus).

Comment: @IgorRivin The only possibly unclear thing was whether some subgroup "contains the connected component of $G$". Since a subgroup of any topological group contains a connected component iff it contains the connected component of 1, this leaves little ambiguity. Anyway you have still left your closing vote.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The closed subgroups of $G$ not containing the identity component lie in countably many conjugacy classes of subgroups. So it is sufficient to show that for each closed subgroup $H$ not containing the identity component, the probability that Haar-random $g_1$ and $g_2$ both lie in some conjugate of $H$ vanishes.

Such pairs are parameterized by the manifold of triples $x \in G/H$, $g_1 \in x H x^{-1}, g_2 \in x H x^{-1}$, which is a manifold of dimension $(\dim G - \dim H) + 2 \dim H = \dim G + \dim H$.

The image of this manifold in $G \times G$ under the projection $(x,g_1,g_2)\mapsto (g_1,g_2)$ must have measure $0$, as it is the image of a smaller-dimensional manifold (as $H$ does not contain the identity we have $\dim H < \dim G$) under a smooth map (by Sard's theorem).

For $H$ a subgroup, the same argument just barely fails to show that the probability that a single $g$ is contained in a conjugate of $H$ vanishes. Indeed in this case both manifolds have dimension $\dim(G)$. This is convenient as that statement is false, because we could take $H$ to be a maximal torus, or alternately the subgroup generated by a reflection in an infinite dihedral group, as in Noam's example.

Comment: What theorem do you use for image of positive dimension under smooth maps to have measure zero? For instance say for closed manifolds $A,B$ under the smooth projection $A\times B\to A$, the image of $A\times\{b\}$ is all of $A$ even if $A$ is a positive codimension submanifold.

Comment: @Ycor I think he meant that the dimension of $G/H \times H \times H$ is lower than the dimension of $G \times G$, so the image is null by Sard's theorem.

Comment: This seems promising, but something is not clear to me. I assumed the map you had in mind was $G/H \times H\times H\to G\times G: (xH,h_1,h_2)\mapsto (xh_1x^{-1},xh_2x^{-1})$. But this isn't well defined. So what is it?

Comment: @Jack Let $M$ be the set of triples $(x,g_1,g_2)$ as I describe. Then the projection map to $G \times G$ from $M$ clearly exists. I claim $M$ is a manifold of dimension $ 2 \dim H+ (\dim G-\dim H)$. The key point is that locally on $G/H$, we can choose a section $s: G/H \to G$ that defines a coset representation, and then $(xH, h_1,h_2) \to (xH, s(x) h_1 s(x)^{-1}, s(x) h_2 s(x)^{-1})$ is perfectly well-defined.

Comment: @YCor Thanks for the correction, and yes Jack has it exactly correct - Sard's theorem is the relevant theorem.

Comment: The last paragraph was more clear before the revision.

Comment: How do you get the claim in your first sentence?

Comment: @WillSawin I see, so you use this local section to show the set you defined is a submanifold, is that right? 
(Oh and by the way - you accidentally wrote "as $H$ does no contain the identity..." instead of "identity component").

Comment: @Jack Yes, we see it is a submanifold of $G/H \times G \times G$. Its image in $G \times G$ is probably not a manifold but we don't need it to be.

Comment: Nice. A few comments (putting things is a fancy, yet convenient language): 1) it is convenient to recall that every compact Lie group is in fact real algebraic and every inclusion of a closed subgroup is algebraic. This could be used to show that you have only countably many conjugacy classes of closed subgroups. 2) Given a closed subgroup $H<G$ the space $X$ consisting of conjugated subgroups is parametrized by $G/N$ where $N$ is the normalizer of $H$ in $G$ (not by $G/H$) and it thus carries a natural structure of a variety.

Comment: 3) There is a tautological bundle over $X$, $Y\to X$ with the fiber over $H$ being the elements of $H$. A natural space to look at is the fibered square $Z=Y\times_X Y$. Its dimension is $\dim(G)-\dim(N)+2\dim(H)\leq \dim(G)+\dim(H)$. 4) Note also that the obvious map $Z\to G\times G$ is an algebraic morphism.

Comment: @UriBader Nice. You might be able to tell that I was inspired by an algebraic geometry style of thinking in coming up with this argument, so this perspective is more appropriate for my preferences.

Comment: This is a very nice answer; it is in fact a much shorter argument to the fact almost every two elements in connected compact Lie groups are generators than the one I knew. Although I have to admit I am not entirely sure how to explain the set you described is a submanifold (without using algebraic geometry); is this obvious?

Comment: @Jack What confuses you about the argument I gave in the first comment on my answer? We want to show it is a submanifold of $G/H \times G \times G$, and we can work locally on $G/H$, where there is a section $G/H \to G$, allowing us to conjugate the submanifold $G/H \times H \times H$ of $G/H \times G \times G$ to obtain our set, thus verifying it is a submanifold.

Comment: @UriBader For point 1, how does that demonstrate the countability of conjugacy classes of closed subgroups? It obviously shows that there are countably many families, but I don't see how you can guarantee conjugacy classes.

Comment: @WillSawin Sorry, for some reason I thought this wasn't enough. My mistake.

Comment: @user44191, sorry for not answering your question yet. I am away of my desk and without a proper computer access for a while. I noticed that you post your question elsewhere. I will answer there when I'm back.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, a much stronger result (due to Ito and Kawada), see Theorem 2.3 in [Emmanuel Breuillard's notes.](https://www.math.u-psud.fr/~breuilla/part0gb.pdf) To wit, if the support of a measure is not contained in a proper closed subgroup then a random walk is eventually equidistributed. If it is contained in a proper closed subgroup, there are two cases: the first is that the subgroup is of codimension zero (in which case it contains the identity component, and we are done), or it is of positive codimension (which is obviously non-generic).

See also Stromberg 1960:

```
MR0114874 (22 #5692) Reviewed 
Stromberg, Karl
Probabilities on a compact group. 
Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 94 1960 295–309.
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but the paper seems to assume that $G$ is generated by neighborhoods of the identity - which seems to exclude the interesting cases we want to study. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: @user44191 I Hmm...You definitely have a point...

Comment: @user44191 see the edit.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand your proof here. What is the measure that you're having generate the random walk?

Comment: What does Ito-Kawada (or numerous related results) have to do with the question? It establishes equidistribution under the assumption that the group generated by the support is dense - however, the latter is precisely what the question is.

Comment: @user44191 and Igor no you not only misread Breuillard's assumption but modify it in your comment. No Breuillard's notes are not confusing, but you seem to be confused anyway and this comment in your post is confusing. It's not "*generated by neighborhoods of 1*" (which is unclear and could be interpreted as "*generated by any neighborhood of 1*" but "**generated by a compact neighborhood of 1**", which is also known as "compactly generated", meaning that some compact neighborhood of 1 generates $G$, and is trivially fulfilled if $G$ is any compact group.

Comment: @YCor In fact, I did interpret Breuillard's hypothesis as "any neighborhood", as did user44191. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @RW My understanding of the result is that if the original measure (which is an atomic measure on the two generators) is not supported in a proper closed subgroup, then you have equidistribution.

Comment: I don't think I understood your answer. What you say is obvious seems to be exactly my question (why isn't the support of the measure - i.e. the two elements in question - not contained in a subgroup of positive codimension?) and what you deduce from Ito-Kawada seems irrelevant to me (albeit very neat).

Comment: @Jack I understand the question even better now :)

Comment: @RW Yes. though the set of subgroups you take cosets of is quite restricted (for example, often a kernel of a one-dimensional rep is enough).

Comment: Actually, it's not quite right - the right necessary and sufficient condition for weak convergence of convolution to the Haar measure on a compact group is that the support of the measure is not contained in a coset of a proper closed normal subgroup. Sorry - I have slightly edited my comment in the meantime.

Comment: @ycor Ah, I was thinking that "generated by a compact neighborhood" would exclude the discrete case, i.e. That it was a condition along the lines of "Every open set contains a compact generating set", which isn't true for a nontrivial discrete group.

Comment: @user44191 The claim is trivial for a discrete group $G$: every subgroup contains the connected component $G^0$, which is just $\{1\}$.

Comment: @jack Of course; talking about discrete groups was only directly relevant to my understanding of the referenced result. I was indirectly talking about cases including Lie groups with multiple components.

Comment: @YCor By "The claim" I was referring to my own question ("does almost every pair of elements generate a subgroup containing the connected component?"), which is obviously trivially true for discrete groups.

Comment: In any case, I understand that we agree that this answer does not solve my question?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't answer your question. The point is that the fact the measure is not supported by any proper subgroup is an assumption. This theorem applies to many Lie groups (such as $\mathbf{R}^n$, $n\ge 2$, in which the subgroup generated by a pair is never dense).

Comment: @YCor $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not as compact as some.

Comment: @Igor yes, thanks a lot although I turned out to know this. I was just illustrating to explain why a theorem of this sort (Ito-Kawada) is not enough to answer the question.

Comment: @Igor part of your answer is wrong "*or it is of positive codimension (which is obviously non-generic)*". At least it's not obvious. Indeed, with a single generator, the classical counterexample $O(2)$ was already mentioned (it's not true that a generic element generates a subgroup whose closure has codimension zero). Possibly for a generic pair something better happens, but not relying on your "obvious" non-argument.

Comment: @YCor Yes, I understand. But my point was simply that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is quite different in many ways....