# Does a compact Lie group have finitely many conjugacy classes of maximal Abelian Lie subgroups?

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups, compactness

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group. An Abelian Lie subgroup $A \leq G$ is a maximal Abelian Lie subgroup if, for any Abelian Lie subgroup $A'$ such that $A \leq A' \leq G$, then $A' = A$.

Of course any maximal torus of $G$ (there is only one, up to conjugacy classes) is a maximal Abelian Lie subgroup, but there are other ones too, for example the Klein 4-group in $\mathrm{SO}(3)$.

What I'm wondering is if the number of conjugacy classes of maximal Abelian Lie subgroups of any compact Lie group $G$ is always finite?

Comment: This may be related, but I think your specific question just barely doesn't fit into any of the answers (or lemmas in them): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265722/countability-of-conjugacy-classes-of-closed-subgroups

Answer (score 8):

Yes it's true. It essentially follows from a lemma quoted in the [linked answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/346377/14094) by user Qayum Khan, which I quote verbatim:

> **Neighboring subgroups theorem** [1942]
>   Any compact subgroup $H$ of an arbitrary Lie group $G$ admits a neighborhood $O$ in $G$ such that any subgroup contained in $O$ is $G$-conjugate to a subgroup of $H$.

Now let by contradiction $(A_n)$ be a sequence of pairwise non-conjugate closed maximal abelian subgroups in a compact Lie group. Let $A$ be a limit point in the Hausdorff topology; this is a compact abelian subgroup. By the above result, for $n$ large enough $A_n$ is conjugate to a subgroup of $A$. By maximality, this means that for $n$ large enough, $A_n$ is conjugate to $A$. This contradicts the non-conjugation.

Comment: Another approach: any abelian (or even nilpotent) subgroup of $G$ is contained in the normalizer of a maximal torus.

Comment: @abx I didn't know this result, which seems to provide an alternating approach reducing the problem to the case when $G^0$ is abelian.

Comment: Bourbaki's Lie IX, §5, Cor. 4 of Théorème 1.

Comment: @abx thanks. Anyway some further argument is needed to deal with $G^0$ abelian.

Comment: Just to emphasize a possible difficulty: while every abelian subgroup is contained in a maximal abelian one (obvious and true in every group), the same is false for nilpotent/maximal nilpotent subgroups in the compact Lie group $(\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z})\rtimes_\pm(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})$.

Comment: @abx, I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4182723/conditions-that-imply-a-subgroup-normalizes-a-maximal-torus/4569157#4569157) on MSE a while ago to which [this](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/910242) is an (perhaps the!) answer.  I have posted an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4569157) before I forget again, but I would prefer to give you the credit.  If you would be willing to post your comment as an answer, then I will delete mine and accept yours.

Comment: @LSpice: Thank you, but that's fine as it is — it's just a reference.